# Using socFunctionAnalyzer with methods defined in a class

Tags: matlab

I am trying to benchmark the performance of a few algorithms each defined in its separate class. Is there a way to run socFunctionAnalyzer for methods defined in a class? I tried creating separate .m files and then passing the class object as a global variable but this is not allowed in socFunctionAnalyzer as well. Are there any ways where I can count the number of addition and mulitplication operations in a class method without having to completely rewrite it?

Comment: You can probably write a function that calls your object method, and analyse that function.